# Make view appear after one minute after is clicked using shared preferences

Tags: android, view, onclick, sharedpreferences

So I need to make a button disappear after is clicked and show up again after one minute. Even when I leave the current activity and I come back to it and one minute has not passed the button should not appear. 
I've tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            preferences.edit().putLong("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();
            //some other logic
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

if ((preferences.getLong("timestamp", 0) + 60000) == System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to make this work? Or is there another way I can make this easier?

Comment: you're using `==` -> It will always return false (or you're very very lucky ;) ) Try to use `<` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do 3 things:

**first:** 
check the timestamp in the *onResume()* of the activity and *setVisibility()* based on that.

add this code to your activity:

```
    @override
protected void onResume(){
  super.onResume()

  if ((preferences.getLong("timestamp", 0) + 60000) <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    rereshImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }else{
    refreshImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }

}
```

**second:**

use this code to show the button again

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){


        @Override
        public void run() {
            refreshImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } , 60000);
```

**third:**

change the condition in *onResume()* to this code:

(equal equal is change to smaller equal)

(because you can not grant that you will come back exacly one minute later.

```
if ((preferences.getLong("timestamp", 0) + 60000) <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        refreshImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: can you explain more the first step? so when i first start the activity the button should be visible. what timestamp should i compare?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Handler` to keep track of One minute and then update the shared preference and in your Activity or Fragment, attach a listener to the shared preference so you get notified whenever a value in the `SharedPreference` changes.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        preferences.edit().putBoolean("isOneMinuteOver", false);
        //some other logic
        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                  preferences.edit().putBoolean("isOneMinuteOver", true);
            }
        }, 60 * 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: that's a great solution. but how can i save the value of the shared preference when the activity is closed? i'm new with this and i don't know exactly how to do it

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is saving your activity status, and then run CountDownTimer in background service. the service will automatically update SharedPreferences and if it's Handler exists currently send message to it to present button. then you may only check service response in it's UI handler or if you come back after long time check SharedPreferences value.